# iOS SwiftUI - Difference between LazyVStack and LazyVGrid

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

As I understand `LazyVStack` and `LazyVGrid` are used to display many rows and saving RAM doing that, but what are the differences between them?

I want to load JSON data though an API and then display thousands of images and videos including details like time, title, description and so on.

Which would be better for that?

I won't accept the first answer but the one that is most informative :)

Comment: Stack is one direction layout. Grid is two directions layout.
If you want to display lot of images/videos, try to use `List`, it support reusable items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between **LazyVGrid** and **LazyVStack** is the container type.

Both of these containers provide **lazy loading** which improves the performance of your app, but the main difference is how it stores its child views.

**LazyVStack** displays its child views from top to bottom in a vertical alignment. It’s similar to a single line.

**LazyVGrid** displays its child views as rows and columns. It’s similar to a chess board.

Base on your desired design, **LazyVStack** should be more suitable since it contains many components and texts.

However, if you are going to just display thousands of image without much detail; similar to Gallery, then **LazyVGrid** should be your first choice, plus it provides a great readability for users too.

Comment: Thanks! I'll go for LazyVStack then